# Swift - editActionsForRowAtIndexPath not working when combined with CAPSPageMenu

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have problem with CAPSPageMenu and adding actions to table rows. Please find below image for my requirement

[image: Requirement image]

I added required table functions but editActionsForRowAtIndexPath was not called. When selecting\clicking a cell and trying to swipe to display the edit buttons, the whole view (table) was being dragged and current view was set/moved to next table view controller.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
```

This problem only happens if I added table view controllers to CAPSPageMenu array.

Here's what I did to initialize pagemenu:

```
 func initPageMenu() {
    self.pageMenu?.controllerArray.removeAll()

    var controllerArray : [MyTableViewController] = []
    let menuHeight: CGFloat = 42.0
    let frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, self.view.frame.width, (self.view.frame.height - self.vacancyDropdownView.frame.height)-menuHeight)

    let myTable1 : MyTableViewController = MyTableViewController(nibName: "MyTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controllerArray.append(myTable1)

    let myTable2 : MyTableViewController = MyTableViewController(nibName: "MyTableViewController", bundle: nil)
    controllerArray.append(myTable2)

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.vacancyDropdownView.frame.height, self.view.frame.width, (self.view.frame.height - self.vacancyDropdownView.frame.height)), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    // Optional delegate
    pageMenu!.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
 }
```